# How to hide smtp authentication information when using NodeMailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using NodeMailer with a contact form and using SMTP to send mail. The transporter code looks like this:

```
transporter = mailer.createTransport({
    auth: {
      user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      pass: 'mypassword'
    }
  });
```

What is the best way to hide this information? I would like to be able to use this method without hardcoding password and email address information into the server code.

Comment: Use environment variables?

Comment: Yeah, I've settled for this.